# Regex or algorithm to match a word or phrase in a string for replacement

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, angularjs

I have a sentence (string) and an array of strings which are words or phrases contained in the sentence.

Each word or phrase in the array is uppercase. The index of the word or phrase in the array corresponds to its sequence in the sentence. For example:

```
var sentence = "Yes. I know him from my neighborhood. Come in!",
    phrases  = ["YES", "I", "HIM", "NEIGHBORHOOD", "COME IN"],
    result   = "";
```

What I want to do, is to match each word or phrase in the sentence and to replace it with the word or phrase wrapped in a  tag. This will allow a user to click on the word and see information about that word (another part of the application already written). I'd like to do this within a single loop. I'm having trouble achieving without regex or secondary loops as words such as "I" and the article "AN" or "A" often match within words.

```
// expected
result = "<span>Yes</span>. <span>I</span> know <span>him<span> from my <span>neighborhood</span>. <span>Come in</span>!";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dynamic regex with the RegExp constructor and use replace:

```
var sentence = "Yes. I know him from my neighborhood. Come in!",
    phrases  = ["YES", "I", "HIM", "NEIGHBORHOOD", "COME IN"];

var regex = RegExp('\\b('+ phrases.join('|') +')\\b', 'gi');
var result = sentence.replace(regex, '<span>$&</span>');
```

Comment: I would add word boundaries in here because if you had `phrases  = ["YES", "NE", "HIM", "NEIGHBORHOOD", "COME IN"]` then the "ne" at the beginning of neighborhood would get spanned instead of "neighborhood" itself.  The OP worried about that case.  I guess in lieu of the word boundaries you could order the phrases....

Comment: @RayToal: You're right, I added the word boundaries.

Comment: Cool, I'll delete mine now.

Answer (score -1):

Use replace method.

```
var str = "Apples are round, and apples are juicy.";
var newstr = str.replace("apples", "oranges", "gi");
print(newstr);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace